# How to run UPDATE and SELECT statement after confirmation?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an application where the user displays their assessment name, date and time in the relevant text inputs. Now what happens is that when the user submits the form, it displays a confirmation.

Below is the code (editsessionadmin.php):

```
 <script>
    function showConfirm(){

    var examInput = document.getElementById('newAssessment').value;
    var dateInput = document.getElementById('newDate').value;
    var timeInput = document.getElementById('newTime').value;

    var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to update the following:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput +  "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput);

    }


    </script>   

    <?php

    $sessionquery = "
    SELECT SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
    FROM Session
    WHERE
    (ModuleId = ?)
    ORDER BY SessionName 
    ";

    $sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$moduleId);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

    $sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

    $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

    $sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    if($sessionnum ==0){
    echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</p>";
    } else { 

    $sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
    $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

    while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
       if(time() > strtotime($dbSessionDate." ".$dbSessionTime)){
             $class = 'red';
        } else {
             $class = 'green';
        }
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' style='color: %s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $class, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;  
    }


    $sessionHTML .= '</select>';


    $assessmentform = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'>
    <p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
    </form>";

    echo $assessmentform;

    }



    $editsession = "<form action=".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])." method='post' id='updateForm'>

        <p><strong>New Assessment's Date/Start Time:</strong></p>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Assessment:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='newAssessment' name='Assessmentnew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Date:</th> 
        <td><input type='text' id='newDate' name='Datenew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Start Time:</th> 
        <td><input type='text' id='newTime' name='Timenew' readonly='readonly' value=''/><span class='timepicker_button_trigger'><img src='Images/clock.gif' alt='Choose Time' /></span> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div id='datetimeAlert'></div>

        <p><input id='updateSubmit' type='submit' value='Update Date/Start Time' name='updateSubmit' onClick='myClickHandler(); return false;'/></p>

        </form>
    ";

    echo $editsession;


    }

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myClickHandler(){ 
         if(editvalidation()){ 
                    showConfirm(); 
         } 
    }

    </script>
```

Now I want to run an UPDATE command to update the exam's date and time in the database after the user has confirmed the confirmation and compile a SELECT query so that if the update happened, then echo it was a success, else echo there was an error.

My question is first of all is the code below correct and second of all where do I place this code so that it runs the commands after the confirmation has been confirmed?

```
 <?php

    $sessionname = (isset($_POST['Assessmentnew'])) ? $_POST['Assessmentnew'] : ''; 
    $sessiondate = (isset($_POST['Datenew'])) ? $_POST['Datenew'] : ''; 
    $sessiontime = (isset($_POST['Timenew'])) ? $_POST['Timenew'] : ''; 

        $updatesql = "UPDATE Session SET SessionDate = ?, SessionTime = ? WHERE SessionName = ?";                                           
        $update = $mysqli->prepare($updatesql);
        $update->bind_param("sss", $sessiondate, $sessiontime, $sessionname);
        $update->execute();

       $query = "SELECT SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime FROM Session WHERE SessionName = ?";
       // prepare query
       $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
       // You only need to call bind_param once
       $stmt->bind_param("sss", $sessionname, $sessiondate, $sessiontime);
       // execute query
       $stmt->execute(); 
       // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
       $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionName, $dbSessionDate, $dbSessionTime);
       //get number of rows
       $stmt->store_result();
       $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();

       if ($numrows == 1){

           echo "<span style='color: green'>Your Assessment's new Date and Time have been updated</span>";

       }else{

           echo "<span style='color: red'>An error has occurred, your Assessment's new Date and Time have not been updated</span>";
    ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Below is code for editsessionadmin.php

```
<script>
function showConfirm(){

var examInput = document.getElementById('newAssessment').value;
var dateInput = document.getElementById('newDate').value;
var timeInput = document.getElementById('newTime').value;

var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to update the following:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput +  "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput);

if (confirmMsg==true)
{
submitform();   
}
}

function submitform()
{

$.post("updatedatetime.php", $("#updateForm").serialize() ,function(data){
var updateFormO = document.getElementById("updateForm");
updateFormO.submit();
}); 

}
</script>   

<?php
    $sessionquery = "
        SELECT SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
        FROM Session
        WHERE
        (ModuleId = ?)
        ORDER BY SessionName 
        ";

        $sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
        // You only need to call bind_param once
        $sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$moduleId);
        // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

        $sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

        $sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

        $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

        $sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

        if($sessionnum ==0){
        echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</p>";
        } else { 

        $sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
        $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

        while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
           if(time() > strtotime($dbSessionDate." ".$dbSessionTime)){
                 $class = 'red';
            } else {
                 $class = 'green';
            }
        $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s' style='color: %s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $class, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i",strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;  
        }

        $sessionHTML .= '</select>';

        $assessmentform = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'>
        <p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
        </form>";

        echo $assessmentform;

        }



        $editsession = "<form action=".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])." method='post' id='updateForm'>

            <p><strong>New Assessment's Date/Start Time:</strong></p>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Assessment:</th>
            <td><input type='text' id='newAssessment' name='Assessmentnew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Date:</th> 
            <td><input type='text' id='newDate' name='Datenew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Start Time:</th> 
            <td><input type='text' id='newTime' name='Timenew' readonly='readonly' value=''/><span class='timepicker_button_trigger'><img src='Images/clock.gif' alt='Choose Time' /></span> </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <div id='datetimeAlert'></div>

            <p><input id='updateSubmit' type='submit' value='Update Date/Start Time' name='updateSubmit' onClick='myClickHandler(); return false;'/></p>

            </form>
        ";

        echo $editsession;


        }

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function myClickHandler(){ 
             if(editvalidation()){ 
                        showConfirm(); 
             } 
        }

        </script>
```

In the above code I added a jquery/ajax function `submitform()` where after the confirmation it will perform a post in the background to the `updatedatetime.php` page. There is where it displays the update and select statments. Problem is that it is not doing the update or displaying the echo in the editsessionadmin.php page

Below is code for updatedatetime.php:

```
    <?php

 // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

    $sessionname = (isset($_POST['Assessmentnew'])) ? $_POST['Assessmentnew'] : ''; 
    $sessiondate = (isset($_POST['Datenew'])) ? $_POST['Datenew'] : ''; 
    $sessiontime = (isset($_POST['Timenew'])) ? $_POST['Timenew'] : ''; 

    $updatesql = "UPDATE Session SET SessionDate = ?, SessionTime = ? WHERE SessionName = ?";                                           
    $update = $mysqli->prepare($updatesql);
    $update->bind_param("sss", $sessiondate, $sessiontime, $sessionname);
    $update->execute();

    $query = "SELECT SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime FROM Session WHERE SessionName = ?";
    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $sessionname, $sessiondate, $sessiontime);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionName, $dbSessionDate, $dbSessionTime);
    //get number of rows
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();

    if ($numrows == 1){

    echo "<span style='color: green'>Your Assessment's new Date and Time have been updated</span>";

    }else{

    echo "<span style='color: red'>An error has occured, your Assessment's new Date and Time have not been updated</span>";



            ?>
```

Comment: From my opinion, first you should break your code into different functions. Otherwise it will grow and become almost unreadable.Try to write a update and a select functions. Also you may know, buy the result of your Update query if there were changes made to rows in the table Session.

Comment: can wrap a `try/catch ` around the update and send error message to browser in the `catch` if update fails

Comment: JS+HTML+PHP+SQL code in one file = [what the hell code](http://wthcode.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately this wall of code is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: I included an update in my question showing the updated code, it is not performing the update and not displaying any echos stating if the update was successful or not. I actually want the echo to be displayed in the editsessionadmin.php page, at the top of the page. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: @MikeB It might help those people who want to to perform a mysqli, mysqli or PDO command after confirming a submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP runs on the server, the user giving the confirmation is on the client. That means you have to use javascript/Jquery to trigger an event when the user gives his confirmation, then call a php that does the UPDATES or other query. This can be done with a AJAX call, or just submiting a form or with a url redirection.

So it should be like this:

1. First `A.php` that gets the form submited with the user data, does some queries and displays the confirmation text. This also has javascript code to submit the confirmation to another `B.php`, normally this would be done with a AJAX call that will receive something in return.
2. Second `B.php` that receives the confirmation of the first `A.php`, does the UPDATES and returns something to tell the first `A.php` all the query went OK. If something goes wrong it could return a error code, or a error message detailing the error.
3. `A.php` shows the return of `B.php` to the user.

UPDATED CODE:

```
$.post("updatedatetime.php", $("#updateForm").serialize() ,function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

The `function(data)` at the end is a callback function, that means that it will be executed once `updatedatetime.php` ends its execution. The variable `data` it receives is the return of `updatedatetime.php` (what you echo in that php)

To check if your AJAX is executing properly, if the variables have values, the return, etc. I would recommend to use Firebug, in its console it will display all this info.

Comment: I will include an update of my code so you can see what the current code is. The only problem I am getting is that it is not displaying an echo stating whether it was a success or not. Give me 10 mins to include the update

Comment: I included an update in my question showing the updated code, it is not performing the update and not displaying any echos stating if the update was successful or not. I actually want the echo to be displayed in the editsessionadmin.php page, at the top of the page. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you show what changes you will make in the update to get it working correctly?

Comment: gimme a sec to check the new code ^^. I'll update my answer when I notice errors.

Comment: Hi, sorry for lateness. The alert showed an error with one of my brackets which fixed it. But I have a tiny problems. It doesn't update the date, in database it just displays it as `0000-00-00`, is that because in the text input it is displayed as `00-00-0000`? If so then where do I change the format back to db date format when updating and selecting the date?

Comment: Also how can I get the echo on wether the update was a success or not to appear at the top of the editsessionadmin.php page?

Comment: about the date format, yup you have to use the same format as MySQL when doing the query. It's usually easier to change it in the PHP just before doing the query.

Comment: and about how to control if it was succesful or not you can do it 2 ways: 1- format the HTML you want to show (when error or when success) in the `updatedatetime.php` and then just add it to a div in `editsessionadmin.php`. something like `$("#targetdiv").html(data)`. The second option would be to just return a 0 or a 1 and then do a if in the jquery callback function to show one message or another.